# How to print a long data frame splitted in several parts put side by side

Tags: r, printing

This question is a variant of "[How to print a long column from a dataframe splited in two columns side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40694757/how-to-print-a-long-column-from-a-dataframe-splited-in-two-columns-side-by-side)" that unfortunately had no answer.
I have a data frame with few columns and many rows that I would like to print in a single page. The following example is the just the beginning of my dataset.

```
structure(list(depnais = c("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", 
"07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", 
"18", "19", "21", "22", "23"), n = c(4051L, 5163L, 3323L, 
1176L, 1394L, 12624L, 2623L, 2194L, 1227L, 3266L, 3111L, 2528L, 
26737L, 7105L, 1096L, 3194L, 5173L, 2592L, 2323L, 5993L, 4952L, 
571L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-23L), .Names = c("depnais", "n"))
```

I would like to output its contents as :

```
#   depnais     n depnais      n depnais      n depnais      n depnais      n depnais     n 
# 1 01       4051 02        5163 03        3323 04        1176 05        1394 06       12624
# 2 07       2623 08        2194 09        1227 10        3266 11        3111 12        2528
# 3 13      26737 14        7105 15        1096 16        3194 17        5173 18        2592
# 4 19       2323 21        5993 22        4952 23         571
```

Today, I split my data frame into two parts : one with a number of rows that is a multiple of the number of splits (6 here) and another with the remainder of the rows, then I reorder the first part.

```
df %>% group_by(depnais) %>% summarise(n=n()) %>% 
  filter(depnais<'96') %>%
  bind_cols(data.frame(g=rep(1:6,16))) %>%
  replyr::replyr_split("g") %>%
  purrr::reduce(bind_cols) %>% select(-matches("^g"))
```

And I print the two data frames separately.

But, actually I don't need the two data frames I make from the orginal one. So: is there a way to directly print the data frame, just specifying how many splits parts there should be?

Comment: Do you want it only for display purpose or you actually want to increase the number of columns with fixed number of rows?

Comment: @Ronak Shah It is only for display. I do no need a modified data frame.

Answer (score 1):

The [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) incarnation of `dcast()` can reshape multiple columns simultaneously. With subsequent reordering and renaming of columns this can be employed to reshape a data.frame with many rows into a wide format.

#### Row first order

as requested by the OP:

```
library(data.table)
# specify number of splits
n_splits <- 6
# reshape to wide format
wide <- as.data.table(df)[, rn := rep(1:.N, each = n_splits, length.out = .N)][
  , dcast(.SD, rn ~ rowid(rn), as.character, value.var = colnames(df), fill = "")][
    , rn := NULL][]
# reorder columns
setcolorder(wide, as.vector(outer(colnames(df), 1:n_splits, paste, sep = "_")))
# rename columns
setnames(wide, rep(colnames(df), n_splits))
wide
```

> ```
>    depnais     n depnais    n depnais    n depnais    n depnais    n depnais     n
> 1:      01  4051      02 5163      03 3323      04 1176      05 1394      06 12624
> 2:      07  2623      08 2194      09 1227      10 3266      11 3111      12  2528
> 3:      13 26737      14 7105      15 1096      16 3194      17 5173      18  2592
> 4:      19  2323      21 5993      22 4952      23  571
> ```

Note, that the result is transposed as requested by the OP, e.g., rows 1 to 6 of `df` are printed horizontally across the first row of the split (*row first order)*.

Incomplete rows in the split are handled automatically. All columns are coerced to character and missing values are filled with `""`.

---

This will work also for other splits, e.g., `n_splits <- 4`:

> ```
>    depnais     n depnais     n depnais    n depnais    n
> 1:      01  4051      02  5163      03 3323      04 1176
> 2:      05  1394      06 12624      07 2623      08 2194
> 3:      09  1227      10  3266      11 3111      12 2528
> 4:      13 26737      14  7105      15 1096      16 3194
> 5:      17  5173      18  2592      19 2323      21 5993
> 6:      22  4952      23   571
> ```

#### Column first order

For the sake of completeness, column first order can be achieved with a slight modification when creating `rn`:

```
library(data.table)
# specify number of splits
n_splits <- 6
# reshape to wide format, fill by column (column first order)
wide <- as.data.table(df)[, rn := rep(1:ceiling(.N/n_splits), length.out = .N)][][
  , dcast(.SD, rn ~ rowid(rn), as.character, value.var = colnames(df), fill = "")][
    , rn := NULL][]
# reorder columns
setcolorder(wide, as.vector(outer(colnames(df), 1:n_splits, paste, sep = "_")))
# rename columns
setnames(wide, rep(colnames(df), n_splits))
wide
```

> ```
>    depnais    n depnais     n depnais    n depnais     n depnais    n depnais    n
> 1:      01 4051      05  1394      09 1227      13 26737      17 5173      22 4952
> 2:      02 5163      06 12624      10 3266      14  7105      18 2592      23  571
> 3:      03 3323      07  2623      11 3111      15  1096      19 2323             
> 4:      04 1176      08  2194      12 2528      16  3194      21 5993
> ```

#### Data

The data originally provided by the OP returned a *corrupt data frame* warning. This on is corrected:

```
df <- structure(list(depnais = c("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", 
"07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", 
"18", "19", "21", "22", "23"), n = c(4051L, 5163L, 3323L, 1176L, 
1394L, 12624L, 2623L, 2194L, 1227L, 3266L, 3111L, 2528L, 26737L, 
7105L, 1096L, 3194L, 5173L, 2592L, 2323L, 5993L, 4952L, 571L)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -22L))
```