# Possible to print() a 100 x 2 tibble side by side in R markdown (pdf)?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I've got a 100 x 2 df. I'm working in R markdown (knitting to PDF). I need to `print()` the entire df, but I'd like to use column breaks so it prints neatly on a single page. [A similar question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52604568/how-to-print-a-long-data-frame-splitted-in-several-parts-put-side-by-side) solution did not work for me.

My date is arranged like this:

````
```df <- data.frame(value=c(letters), count=c(1:26))```
````

Ideally, I'd like the df to print in, say, three side by side columns when I knit to PDF. This would avoid having to scroll down two pages to review the `print()`.

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Have you tried this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56445149/how-can-i-split-a-table-so-that-it-appears-side-by-side-in-r-markdown